# How to get :before css element value

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, automated-tests, capybara

I have this minor stupid point I have to cover with automated test, and its driving me crazy, I am not able to get the value of :before css element, the code is really simple as the test also, but I still need some help on it. Here is the code I have.

```css
.text-currency-positive::before {

    content: "+ ";

}
```

```html
<div class="amount">
  <span class="text-currency text-currency-positive text-monospace text-nowrap">
    ::before
    100,00 €
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Which value? The computed value(size etc)? Text node value?

Comment: either a "+" or "-" prefix, and that is what i want to grab!

Comment: You mean the text value?

Comment: a I get it, you want the first index of value

Comment: yeah, sorry for the inconvenience :D

Comment: I get it, hold on a minute, this is bit more complicated than it should be , I am working on the solution.

Comment: Just to add, with the code below, you can extract the value and then do your conditionals if(-){}, elseif (+) {} etc.

Comment: yeah it would all be grat if i wasnt working in Ruby, i really do appreciate the effort but i dont find it helpful, yet, sory

Comment: Oh, it showed under css or JS questions. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here we go:

```
<h1 class="element">The value of my pseudo element is: </h1> // see the class
```

Then we add the pseudo element:

```
.element:before {
content: '+NEW';

}
```

Now the JS:

```
var content = window.getComputedStyle(  
document.querySelector('.element'), ':before' // target the classes pseude
 ).getPropertyValue('content');  // here we can get the computed styles/values
```

This is not enough, as this would return a string ..."+". So we do this:

```
var makeVar = content.replace(/"/g, ''); // replace the quotes with nothing
var firstLetter = makeVar.charAt(0);     // here we get the value of first char after we have replaced the quotes
```

Display it:

```
var h1 = document.querySelector(".element");
h1.innerHTML += " content is: " + firstLetter;
```

If you do not replace the quotes with the regex, youll get "+" returned, but maybe that is what you want.

Cheers, link:

https://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/ooJqem